# update ServiceConfiguration.cscfg file without need of developer

Tags: azure, configuration, staging

I am new to windows azure. So i am doing RnD. Can we update ServiceConfiguration.cscfg directly or we have to deploy the role through visual studio.

I am getting below error while updating ServiceConfiguration.cscfg. or we can't update it for staging environment?
"The configuration could not be uploaded for the staging deployment of cloud service ."

Answer (score 1):

Not 100% sure what you're trying to do but there are two scenarios where you would be updating the config file:

- **You are changing value of an existing item in config file**: If all you want to do is change the value of an existing item in the config file, you can do it through Azure Portal as well. There's no need to redeploy the application.
- **You have added/removed an item in config file**: If you have added a new entry in the config file or removed an existing entry from the config file, then you have to redeploy your role.

Comment: +1, just don't forget that if you change anything on the "configure" tab then the changes will persist until the deployment is deleted or updated. So it'd be good to document the changes and then perhaps incorporporate the changes into where you sources are stored so that next time you deploy you have the changes.

Comment: Thanks... But it doesn't allow me to update.. I have downloaded the ServiceConfiguration.cscfg from configure tab.. It doesn't allow me to update the same file.

Comment: What happens when you try to change the setting manually instead of uploading the file?

Comment: Yes.. Manually i can update without any issue. Just upload of file is an issue.

Comment: Are you doing it in preview portal or current portal? Please check if the file is not corrupt.